# The Body does not stretch 100% it's width

Tags: html, css, stretch

I am trying to figure out why the body does not stretch 100% the width of the webpage.  I have tried many css rules but it seems that nothing work.  When you open the page on the browser you'll see it covers all the screen but the problem is that you can scroll the page to the right side of the screen creating a white space.  I have never experienced this before.  Can anyone go see and inspect the code? The website is http://lotopluspr.com

Comment: Please put up some code you are facing issue with.

Comment: Is this just cleverly designed spam?

Comment: Dear Evan. I just see your message.  No, it was as real issue I had with a website I was building.  It was fixed thanks to a person who took the time to inspect the code and found the problem which I was able to fix.  I don't know how you may help if you cannot see the problem.  Now I have another situation which I just posted, this time with the Carousel.  If I don't write down the urls, how people like you may help?  Maybe I am a rookie here, but I don't see any other way to show the problem.  Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too wide element inside footer, some "Live traffic stats" link. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Z1a.jpg).

Comment: YOU GOT IT ANDREW!!!!!!  I did not notice that.  I deleted the cloumn and works.  Now I have to figure out how to code it back.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```